# Django ImageField has no url attribure associated with it

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to create a one page app where you can upload a picture to the database and it would display it in the index page.

I can't get the photo to display, even though when calling in the html part `{{post.picture}}` it returns the path of the picture

media settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

view:

```
from random_tasks_app import forms
from random_tasks_app.models import Post

def index(request):

    posts = Post.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    else:
        form = forms.UploadImageForm()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form, 'posts' : posts})
```

models:

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', blank=True, null=True)
```

forms:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from random_tasks_app.models import Post

class UploadImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
    {%for post in posts%}
      <img src="{{ post.picture.url }}"/>
    {%endfor%}
  </body>
</html>
```

The error:

```
raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)
ValueError: The 'picture' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

thanks.

Comment: Where is `hotel` coming from?

Comment: Copied this part of the code from some website when I got the error (thought I might have missed a curly bracket or something), didn't noticed that, I changed it to post but I still get the same error.

Comment: Change your code to this in html file, to see what are your URLs:    {%for post in posts%}
      <p>{{ post.picture.url }}</p>
    {%endfor%}

Comment: @AndreyBorzenko This returns an error. it just returns:
The 'picture' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: @AndreyBorzenko I got it working, I get something like '/media/photos/Screenshot_70.png' when uploading the picture.
tried this but it didn't seem to work :      
<img src="{{post.picture.url}}" alt="No Image" width="500" height="400">

Answer (score 0):

you can add a **default** attribute it will be solved

```
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='default/', blank=True, null=True, default='default.jpg' )
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, but I've noticed a weird thing, from some reason the HTML does not show up any image, even if it's not related to django. I think it's something about the routing.

Comment: Seems as though django is blocking any image form being displayed, even if I'm trying to show an image that does not use django functionality 
```
<img src="C:\Users\amitr\OneDrive\Desktop\my_projects\random_tasks\template\test_image.jpg" alt="No Image" width="500" height="400">```

This works if I open it using normal html, but when running it on the django server it just doesn't work

Comment: maybe , i think if you submit the ImageField empty django will raise error

Comment: solved it thanks. forgot to add: + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
at the end of the urls.py url pattern